# Is this question too broad ("general", "best practices") or on-topic for SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, needs-more-focus

Another user and I disagree about whether [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29393526/1445366) is too broad.

The OP asks three questions about a voice dictation method in WatchKit, the SDK for Apple Watch:

> 1. What languages are supported for input?
> 2. Is it possible to set the desired language programmatically?
> 3. Can I programmatically get the selected language?

I think this is clearly a programming question: it's three specific questions about a specific method in a specific SDK. In fact, due to its specificity, I was able to answer the question very succinctly.

However, another user writes:

> This question is very broad. This site is intended for providing answers to concise questions related to specific programming issues/tools.

And:

> This is not a specific programming question. You are asking about general features of an API/tool (1), best practices (2) and then finally about something that might be considered remotely related to actual programming (if that, 3). Hence "too broad"

I disagree with this. The OP is asking about *specific* features. I see no mention of best practices, and the whole question seems to be about programming at its core. It is both "a specific programming problem" and "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Is this question too broad?

Comment: In my view, the OP is asking very general clarifications. The things he is asking for can only be described as a form of Dev kit/API documentation. You could even say that he is asking for an "off-site" resource, i.e. wherever, Apple chose to put the full docs on it's watch development platform...

Comment: @Kris I might agree with you for his question #1 if the documentation for that method answered it. However, the documented set of languages is on a different site entirely, and it requires experience writing software for the platform to make the connection. (Apple's documentation is poor in this case.)

Comment: His question #2 isn't addressed anywhere in the official documentation.

Comment: OK, but that still does not mean it is not somehow related to the API and it's spec or a best practice rather than being a specific issue with the coding itself. It is not that he has issues with calling a method, rather he is asking what method to use... For me, that feels distinctly off-topic. That is all I can really say :) But then again, it is good that you brought it up for discussion. The line is probably thin.